# Speed up count on distinct

Tags: sql, postgresql

My query return the volume of each field where data is not null.

```
SELECT COUNT(field1) AS field1, COUNT(field2) AS field2, COUNT(field3) AS field3
FROM (
    SELECT field1, field2, field3
    FROM table1, table2
    WHERE table1.id=table2.idt1 
    ORDER BY table1.id ASC
    LIMIT 10000
) AS rq
```

table1.id is The primary key of table1 and table2.idt1 is the secondary key of table2.
This query is working perfectly well, but if I need to return the DISTINCT volume of each field, like this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(field1)) AS field1, COUNT(DISTINCT(field2)) AS field2, COUNT(DISTINCT(field3)) AS field3
FROM (
    SELECT field1, field2, field3
    FROM table1, table2
    WHERE table1.id=table2.idt1 
    ORDER BY table1.id ASC
    LIMIT 10000
) AS rq
```

Problems begins... The query is working on and do the job, but the performances are of course very much slower than without the DISTINCT clause.

Each field of table1 and table2 are indexes with btree

```
CREATE INDEX field1_index ON table1 USING btree (field1)
CREATE INDEX field2_index ON table1 USING btree (field2)
CREATE INDEX field3_index ON table2 USING btree (field3)
```

How can I speed up this DISTINCT count ? Maybe with better indexes ?

Thanks for help

Comment: You should learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is ***NOT*** a function

Comment: What's the point of making a join and then counting the distinct values from the rows that have just been duplicated by that very join? Would it not be better to count without joining?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried something similar in a big table. (12 Millions rows)

Without the `DISTINCT` it takes 10 seconds.

With the `DISTINCT` like your code it take 19 seconds.

**Puting the `DISTINCT` inside the subquery takes 11 seconds**

```sql
SELECT COUNT(field1) AS field1, COUNT(field2) AS field2, COUNT(field3) AS field3
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT(field1) AS field1, DISTINCT(field2) AS field2, DISTINCT(field3) AS field3
    FROM table1, table2
    WHERE table1.id=table2.idt1 
    ORDER BY table1.id ASC
    LIMIT 10000
) AS rq
```

Other thing, if you only want to filter `NULL` data, you can make that in the where clause instead of using distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres does not optimize `COUNT(DISTINCT)` very well.  You have multiple such expressions, which makes it a bit harder.  I am going to suggest using window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum_1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as field1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum_2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as field2, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum_3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as field3 
FROM (SELECT field1, field2, field3,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field1 ORDER BY field1) as seqnum_1,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field2 ORDER BY field2) as seqnum_2,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field3 ORDER BY field3) as seqnum_3
      FROM table1 JOIN
           table2
           ON table1.id=table2.idt1 
      ORDER BY table1.id ASC
      LIMIT 10000
     ) rq
```

EDIT:

It occurs to me that the `row_number()` might be processed *before* the `limit`.  Try this version:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum_1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as field1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum_2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as field2, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum_3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as field3 
FROM (SELECT field1, field2, field3,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field1 ORDER BY field1) as seqnum_1,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field2 ORDER BY field2) as seqnum_2,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field3 ORDER BY field3) as seqnum_3
      FROM (SELECT field1, field2, field3
            FROM table1 JOIN
                 table2
                 ON table1.id = table2.idt1 
            ORDER BY table1.id ASC
            LIMIT 10000
           ) t
     ) rq
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, but in my case it seems too slow, even worse. It runs from severals minutes and it is not finish yet. Against 5 minutes with the DISTINCT clause.

Comment: Indeed your edit method works well, but it takes 818 secondes to run, against 437 secondes for the basic DISTINCT clause

Comment: @Macbernie . . . What are the types of these fields?  A few `count(distinct)` on 10,000 rows should not be taking so long.

Comment: No indeed @Gordon, on 10,000 it take 1 seconde (as DISTINCT), but on huge volumes (with LIMIT ALL in my test) it is slower. Fields are text or bigint.

Comment: @Macbernie . . . long text values would be a problem.

Comment: Is a varchar really more efficient ?

Comment: @Macbernie . . . I think it is the length of the field, not the specific type, that would impede performance.